# Attempting to query on first-time attenders historically

Tags: mysql, sql-server, date

I should start by saying I'm very much a novice to this.

I'm trying to write a sql query to give me the following:

Date/         ID/   Name/       Tickets/   Amount/    First Show ever

19/05/2016/     BFDFRE002/   J.Smith/     2/         £15/       10/10/2014

I can get all the information easily enough except for first show EVER. I am using date parameters in my query as I am looking for people who have bought tickets for a specific show - but this parameter is then also used for my first show column, whereas I want it to be the date of their first show ever since time began (ie no date parameters)!

My query is along the lines of:

```
SELECT      EventDate, CustomerID, dcName, 
                dshowName, Count(TransactNum) AS tickets, Sum(ItemPrice) as Amount,
                MIN(EventDate) AS First_Show

FROM         Dwh.DimEvents LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  Dwh.DimShows LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  Dwh.DimShowTypes ON Dwh.DimShows.dshShowTypeGuid = Dwh.DimShowTypes.dstGuid ON 
                  Dwh.DimEvents.devShowGuid = Dwh.DimShows.dshGuid RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                  Dwh.DimClients RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                  Dwh.FactTickets ON Dwh.DimClients.dcClientGUID = Dwh.FactTickets.ftClientGuid ON Dwh.DimEvents.devGuid = Dwh.FactTickets.ftEventGuid


WHERE     (EventDate > CONVERT(DATETIME,  '2016-05-17 00:00:00', 102))
Group by EventlDate, CustomerID, dcName, dshName
```

I thought that I would need to have a sub query, but I can't have 2 select queries so now I'm a bit stuck.

My ultimate aim is to have a column that tells me whether the first show date is before the event date meaning that this is NOT their first time (or conversely if first show date = event date then they are a First Time Attender) - but I thought initially this would be a first step

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Wolfgang.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Please don't use LEFT and also RIGHT OUTER JOIN in the same query.

Comment: Duly noted! Thanks.

Comment: Sorry - SQL server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CROSS APPLY` to pull in the first event date separately, example below, based on the comments above of not using the subquery will be needed to amended to match. Have also assumed that `CustomerID` is from `Dwh.DimClients` and have given the table the alias of `c` to reference from the cross apply.

```
SELECT  EventDate ,
    CustomerID ,
    dcName ,
    dshowName ,
    COUNT(TransactNum) AS tickets ,
    SUM(ItemPrice) AS Amount ,
    f.FirstEventDate AS First_Show
FROM    Dwh.DimEvents
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Dwh.DimShows
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Dwh.DimShowTypes ON Dwh.DimShows.dshShowTypeGuid = Dwh.DimShowTypes.dstGuid ON Dwh.DimEvents.devShowGuid = Dwh.DimShows.dshGuid
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN Dwh.DimClients C
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN Dwh.FactTickets ON Dwh.DimClients.dcClientGUID = Dwh.FactTickets.ftClientGuid ON Dwh.DimEvents.devGuid = Dwh.FactTickets.ftEventGuid
    CROSS APPLY ( SELECT    MIN(EventDate) FirstEventDate
                  FROM      Dwh.DimEvents
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN Dwh.DimShows
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN Dwh.DimShowTypes ON Dwh.DimShows.dshShowTypeGuid = Dwh.DimShowTypes.dstGuid ON Dwh.DimEvents.devShowGuid = Dwh.DimShows.dshGuid
                            RIGHT OUTER JOIN Dwh.DimClients
                            RIGHT OUTER JOIN Dwh.FactTickets ON Dwh.DimClients.dcClientGUID = Dwh.FactTickets.ftClientGuid ON Dwh.DimEvents.devGuid = Dwh.FactTickets.ftEventGuid
                  WHERE     CustomerID = C.CustomerID
                ) f
WHERE   ( EventDate > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-05-17 00:00:00', 102) )
GROUP BY EventlDate ,
    CustomerID ,
    dcName ,
    dshName;
```

Comment: Thom, that is absolutely brilliant. Thankyou so much!!

Comment: Now, just one last thing - how would I add a column in the results to give a 'TRUE' if Event date is equal to First-Show or else a 'FALSE' if not?

Comment: It's ok - I discovered I just needed to use a case when statement for this additional column